# why $-$ sign in DTFT pair for constant

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dtft

In discrete time Fourier transform, The DTFT of constant 1 is 
$$\sum_{l=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(\omega-2\pi l) $$. I have confusion that why there is $-$ sign, why it can't be $$\sum_{l=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(\omega+2\pi l) $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can also have a $+$ sign, there's no difference. Write down a part of the sum (around index $l=0$) and try to see that in both cases you're summing the same terms, just in a different order.

More formally, take one of the two sums, transform the index by changing its sign ($k=-l$) and see what you get.